# PayPal _cart Upload to Sandbox never allows login

Tags: php, paypal, shopping-cart

So I have been doing a lot of Googling on PayPal's _cart Upload ability and so far, this is what I have managed to put together. And this seems to be working just fine; I am taken to a PayPal page with the purchase info and it asks me to login. But when I login with a Sandbox buyer account, it simply shows that it's logging me in but it never logs me in nor does it allow me to complete the purchase. The merchant sandbox account is working fine as it displays the Example store name on the PayPal page.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx@xxx.xxx">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="3">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Foo">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="22.97">
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping2_1" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="22.97">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://******/order.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
    <input class="paypal_button" type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but03.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

Am I doing something wrong when I'm logging in to PayPal or is the _cart upload ability deprecated after PayPal moved to a new a developer site and API? Any and all help would be appreciated it, I have been banging my head against the wall for hours trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I don't think it'd make a difference but I am using PHP to generate the checkout information.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just submitted a payment using your code and my own sandbox account.  It worked fine for me.

PayPal's servers can sometimes be pretty finicky with cookies in browsers.  Close your browser (all instances of it so it's completely closed) and then reopen it and try again.  Make sure you're signed in at developer.paypal.com before you try it and you should be just fine.

Comment: When you say logged in at developer.paypal.com, you mean with my real PayPal account, right?

Comment: Well, you go to http://developer.paypal.com and it will have you log in there with your real PayPal credentials, yes.  But then you just leave that developer account logged in while you test in another browser tab.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it was a cookie issue as I tried it once again and it worked now. Thank you!